# HTML table auto refresh issue with Edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, mustache

I am constructing a html page from an array of json objects. Every object in the array is shown as separate table in the html page.
Say if the array has 5 objects then html will have 5 tables. I am using `Mustache.js` to construct the table.

I have to refresh this page for every 5 mins.

Every table has "Edit" button in the top. When Edit is clicked then the table will be in "Edit mode".
While doing auto refresh , I want to stop the refresh for the tables which are in "Edit mode".

Please suggest some solution for this.

I am trying to use

```
$("#"+divId).load(URL);
```

But this loads the raw data into the table.It is not populating the appropriate column and style is not applied.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For stop refresh table in edit mode, you can do something like this:

```
<table data-edit-mode="false" class="table">
...
</table>

<script>
    // example function of update tables
    setInterval(function(){
        $.each($('.table'), function(k,v){
            if ($(v).data('edit-mode') === false) {
                //update code
            }
        });
    }, 60 * 5 * 1000);
</script>
```

Set `data-edit-mode=true` when you press `button` edit

## update

https://jsfiddle.net/rdgeejbc/2/

Comment: I need Mustache.js based solution

Comment: check jsfiddle example

Comment: Thanks waki . I will take a look on your solution as update tomorrow.